# Suppressed: io.netty.handler.ssl.StacklessSSLHandshakeException: Connection closed while SSL/TLS handshake was in progress

Tags: java, ssl, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

What I want to achieve

- send http requests to a third party service that has TLS enabled using Reactor Netty http client and Spring Webflux WebClient at a very high traffic (1000+ requests per second)

What I tried

- using this code:

```
    @Bean
    public ClientHttpConnector getClientHttpConnector() {
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true).metrics(true, Function.identity()).protocol(HttpProtocol.HTTP11).secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getSslContext()).handshakeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(59))));
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public WebClient getWebClient(final ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector) {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(hostAndPort).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(clientHttpConnector).build();
    }

public SslContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            final var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream("/path/to/keystore")) {
                final var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                keyStore.load(file, "password".toCharArray());
                keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
            }
            return SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(keyManagerFactory).trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

please note `.handshakeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(59))));`

Issue:

- Reproducible 100% of the time, I am getting this exception:

```
10.1xx.2xx.1xx:8888]

        The connection observed an error
        java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1067)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
        at reactor.netty.channel.MicrometerChannelMetricsHandler$TlsMetricsHandler.channelInactive(MicrometerChannelMetricsHandler.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Suppressed: io.netty.handler.ssl.StacklessSSLHandshakeException: Connection closed while SSL/TLS handshake was in progress
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(Unknown Source)
```

Question:

As I mentioned, I have `.handshakeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(59))));` configured.
I even tried changing this magic number to some crazy values such as Integer.MAX_VALUE
However, it seems not to be the correct configuration, as I am getting this 100% of the time.

On the third party server side, there is no downtime, and they are able to serve traffic to clients other than me at the same timestamp.

What is the appropriate configuration in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Take a tcp dump, if the other peer closes the connection then you need to find why that peer decided to close it. Check logs etc. ...

Comment: What does the `getSslContext()` method look like? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: Does the server trust your client certificiate?

Comment: Yes it does, verified on the server the handshake is successful

Comment: does the server have some firewall configuration?

Comment: @PatPanda besides the message, are the requests successful? In the spring cloud repo the issue was mentioned as logged but not blocking/breaking the flow https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2493

Answer (score 1):

You can enable debug for the javax.net package while launching your application, using `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL` or better full logging coverage `-Djavax.net.debug=ALL` java options.

There are many timeouts you should configure, and set only one can work out of the box, but sometimes not. Check your configuration.

```
HttpClient.create()
  .secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient())
    .defaultConfiguration(SslProvider.DefaultConfigurationType.TCP)
    .handshakeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
    .closeNotifyFlushTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
    .closeNotifyReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)));
```

Do you have configured a proxy ? Here an example with HTTP, not HTTPS.

```
HttpClient.create()
  .proxy(spec -> spec.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
    .host("proxy")
    .port(8080)
    .connectTimeoutMillis(60000));
```

Reactive webclient HTTP response timeout :

```
webClient.get()
  .uri("https://stackoverflow.com")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(JsonNode.class)
  .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
```

Reactive webclient HTTP response timeout with exception handling :

```
webClient.get()
  .uri("https://stackoverflow.com")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(JsonNode.class)
  .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
  .onErrorMap(ReadTimeoutException.class, ex -> new HttpTimeoutException("ReadTimeout"))
  .onErrorReturn(SslHandshakeTimeoutException.class, new TextNode("SslHandshakeTimeout"))
  .doOnError(WriteTimeoutException.class, ex -> log.error("WriteTimeout"))
```

For the general handshake errors, considering the server part only :

- The protocol used by client is not supported by server.
- Cipher suite used by client is not supported by server.
- Incorrect certificate :

  - URL host name doesn't match host name on server certificate.
  - Incomplete/invalid certificate chain presented to client.
  - Revoked/expired SSL/TLS certificate sent to the client or server.
  - Replacement of self-signed certificates in internal networks has
    caused a path-building error.
  - Client can't communicate with SNI-enabled server.

Other causes of handskake failures can be :

- Incorrect System Time
- Man in the middle attack